# How to create a fixed-position column within a Bootstrap-4 modal dialogue box

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm making a Bootstrap 4 modal dialogue.  I already have the top (header) and bottom (footer) static, and the modal body scrolls.  I'd like to divide the modal body into a 40% wide left column that is also static, and 60% right column that scrolls (the main body).

(https://i.imgur.com/INLEngZ.png)

I've tried many different permutations of static and sticky, and the left column always scrolls with the rest of the modal body.

```
<!-- Modal lightbox for bg preview and cancel/save selections -->
<div class="modal fade" id="bgSelector" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" width="100%" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form name="bgForm" id="bgForm" action="#blah" method="post">
        <div class="modal-header bg-white d-block" style="position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 1000;">
          <button type="button" class="close float-right align-items-start" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h5 class="text-info text-center" id="modalTitle">Select background image</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body d-flex">
          <div class="column postition-sticky" style="width: 40%; border: 1px solid red;">
            <p class="w-100 text-center" style="z-index: 1000;">Select an image to use in the background...</p>
            <!-- Dynamic preview goes here -->
          </div>
          <div class="theme-list column" style="width: 60%; border: 1px solid blue;">
            <!-- Body content goes here -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center bg-white" style="position: sticky; bottom: 0; z-index: 1000;">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="themeForm" formmethod="post" formaction="#blah">Save Background Image</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a child element [which can be scrolled] inside this element:

```
 <div class="theme-list column" style="width: 60%; border: 1px solid blue;">
        <!-- Child element which can be scrolled goes here -->
    </div>
```

set parent element overflow-y:scroll and fixed height, and the child element should have height:auto.

Also for suggestion the inline style: width: 60%; border: 1px solid blue; is not a good idea. maybe you should put it inside css/scss file. Or better just use bootstrap classes.

Comment: The borders were just for debugging visualization. :)